# Take conditional only if value is numeric

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am running some webscraping code to collect football player information. However, one of the players has an extra attribute which messes up the order of my dictionary.

I can bypass this by possibly running a conditional where if the value is not numeric for number 3 skip it and go to the next and use the next value as 3, though I am unsure how to do this as I reckon it could be done by running a `try` and `exception`.

For example:

```
links = ['https://en.soccerwiki.org/player.php?pid=45675',
 'https://en.soccerwiki.org/player.php?pid=45710',
 'https://en.soccerwiki.org/player.php?pid=47094',
 'https://en.soccerwiki.org/player.php?pid=47150']

#grab content
for t in player_link[183:190]:
    r = requests.get(t)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    all_b = soup.find('table', {'class':'tabledata'}).find_all("td")
    for k in all_b:
        store_test['data'].append(k.text)

#split content into respective keys

player_test = {'fullname':[],'club':[],'age':[],'DOB':[],'nation':[],'height':[],'weight':[],'hairColour':[],'hairstyle':[],'skinColour':[],'facialHair':[],'squadNumber':[]}
for i in zip(itertools.cycle([1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]), store_test['data']):
    if i[0] == 1:
        player_test['fullname'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 2:
        player_test['club'].append(i[1])
#Problem arises in three where an extra attribute is given by one of the players
#messing up the order where age should take place
#my attempt
        try:
            if i[0] == 3:
                if type(i[1]) is int:
                    player_test['age'].append(i[1])

    elif i[0] == 3:
        player_test['age'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 4:
        player_test['DOB'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 5:
        player_test['nation'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 6:
        player_test['height'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 7:
        player_test['weight'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 8:
        player_test['hairColour'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 9:
        player_test['hairstyle'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 10:
        player_test['skinColour'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 11:
        player_test['facialHair'].append(i[1])
    elif i[0] == 12:
        player_test['squadNumber'].append(i[1])
```

Comment: Invalid syntax - you have a try but no except .... is that your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all player stats from the links you have in question, you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    "https://en.soccerwiki.org/player.php?pid=45675",
    "https://en.soccerwiki.org/player.php?pid=45710",
    "https://en.soccerwiki.org/player.php?pid=47094",
    "https://en.soccerwiki.org/player.php?pid=47150",
]

all_data = []
for link in links:
    print(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
    data = {}
    for th in soup.select("#realLifeTable th"):
        data[th.get_text(strip=True)] = th.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
    all_data.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                    Full Name                 Club Age      Date of Birth   Nation Height (cm) Weight (kg) Hair Colour Hairstyle Skin Colour Facial Hair Squad Number On Loan at
0        Kieran John Trippier      Atlético Madrid  30  19 September 1990  England         177          71  Dark Brown   Cropped       White     Stubble           23        NaN
1  Álvaro Borja Morata Martín      Atlético Madrid  28    23 October 1992    Spain         189          85       Black   Cropped       Olive       Clean      Not set   Juventus
2          Idrissa Gana Gueye  Paris Saint-Germain  31  26 September 1989  Senegal         174          72       Black   Cropped       Black       Clean           27        NaN
3           Wissam Ben Yedder            AS Monaco  31     12 August 1990   France         170          68       Black   Cropped       Olive       Clean            9        NaN
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: what's the difference between using `.get_text()` and `.text`. Is it the ability to add those extra paramters? So `.get_text(strip=True)` as opposed to `.text.strip()`?

Comment: @chitown88 If there are tags within, for example `<div>  text1<div>  text2 </div>  text3</div>` then `.text.strip()` strips only whitespaces from left/right, but `.get_text(strip=True)` will strip all whitespaces (the result is `text1text2text3`). Also, you can add `separator=` parameter.

Comment: ah ok. Cool. I'm always learning something new from your posts. Great job, as usual!